# Помогите разобраться с callback interface

Tags: java, android, callback

Приветствую и благодарю за проявленный интерес к вопросу.

Имеется Fragment и Activity

```
public class fragment_qr extends Fragment {
public interface IFragment {
    public void onDecoded(String string);
}
public IFragment iFragment;
```

далее внутри любого абстрактного события во фрагменте я создаю обращение к интерфейсу куда передаю значение localString

```
iFragment.onDecoded(localString);
```

В теле активити же я применяю интерфейс к классу

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements IFragment {
```

и добавляю требуемый метод

```
@Override
public void onDecoded(String string) {
    printSomething(string);
}
```

При отладке вылетает

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void *.fragments.fragment_qr$IFragment.onDecoded(String)' on a null object reference
```

Таки только начинаю разбираться, прошу помочь советом.

Comment: UPD: При дебаге ругается на строку iFragment.onDecoded(localString);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тело фрагмента необходимо добавить override метод

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        iFragment= (IFragment) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implements IFragment");
    }
}
```